# Selecionar apenas um item em meio a duas listboxes

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

Opa! Galera, eu queria selecionar apenas um item em meio a duas listbox, imaginando a listbox como sendo um radiobutton, se eu selecionar um item em uma, deixa de estar selecionado na outra.
Eu tentei assim:

```
private void listBoxQuestoesObjetivas_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBoxQuestoesSubjetivas.ClearSelected();
}

private void listBoxQuestoesSubjetivas_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBoxQuestoesObjetivas.ClearSelected();
}
```

O problema é que quando eu clico em uma, desseleciona nas duas, isso é muito estranho '-'
*Lembrando que estou usando o Microsoft.Net Framework 2.0*

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte, mas logicamente alterando os nomes dos controles para os seus.

```
    private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    private void listBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Assim também funciona:

```
    private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox2.ClearSelected();
    }

    private void listBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.ClearSelected();
    }
```

Comment: Sua primeira sugestão eu já tentei e da exatamente a mesma coisa, a segunda sugestão é exatamente igual a minha

Comment: Não é igual, você esta usando o evento "SelectedIndexChanged", se você usar o evento que está na resposta funciona 100%, observe que na resposta está com o evento "Click". O evento SelectedIndexChanged limpa os selecionados após você já ter clicado no controle, o evento "Click" limpa os selecionados antes do SelectedIndex ser alterado.